# Hibernate only sets length within @Column on field, not attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have some classes with which I'm exploring Hibernate.  One of them has a name field, and I attempted to set the length of it with the following:

```
private String firstname;
@Column(length=25)
public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
public void setFirstName(String first) { this.firstName = first; }
```

I did this with several fields, all in the same pattern -- I put the @Column on the property firstName instead of on the field firstName.  I have read that this determines how the framework accesses your field's information -- either directly from the field, or from the getter/setter of the field.

The idea that length can be put in @Column in that position is confirmed somewhat in the documentation; in the Hibernate Reference Documentation, in section 5.1.4.1.4., "Declaring column attributes", it has the following lines:

```
@Column(updatable = false, name = "flight_name", nullable = false, length=50)
public String getName() { ... }
```

so they put the length attribute on @Column in front of a getter.

The problem is that it doesn't work.  My little test program adds a property for hbm2ddl.auto to "create", so that it drops everything and re-creates it; the configuration also echoes the generated SQL.  With @Column in front of the getter, not the field, the generated field is VARCHAR(255), same as without @Column.

When I move @Column to be in front of the field instead, it is created with the designated length of 25.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something (else) about the configuration of Hibernate fields with annotations?  Unfortunately I don't want the other attributes mentioned in the docs, and I would think it strange that you had to specify one of those to get length recognized anyway.

Comment: You have to be consistent. All annotations must be on the fields, or all annotations must be on the getters. If you mix both, half of them must be ignored (the location of `@Id` defines where Hibernate looks for annotations).

Comment: According to the Hibernate Reference (H version 3.6.10, ref section 5.1.4.1.2 "Access Type", all annotations *in an inheritance hierarchy* must be consistent, and `@Id` defines the default Access Type (not the default position for annotations).  Do you have a reference for what you've stated?  I've also found some other similar statements that aren't the same; I'm willing to assume I should take the HibRef as a better source than others, but it is an assumption...

Comment: My apologies, you appear to be right; Once I changed the AccessType to be explicitly PROPERTY, config failed because Id annotation was on the field instead of the property.  Once I moved Id from the field to the getter, other config things failed because they were in the wrong place.  If you know of a place where this is actually stated, I would still like to see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mixed access mode (i.e. use annotations on fields for some properties and on getters for others) you have to take a few extra steps.

First, set the default access type for the entity. For example, this will set the default access type to FIELD:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MyEntity { … }
```

Then for the properties that you want to annotate on the getters, explicitly set the access type to PROPERTY:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(length=25)
public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
```

Comment: Ok, I guess whatever I read that indicated that the placement of the annotations determined type was just wrong, possibly getting confused over the placement of the @Id annotation and the fact that it determines the default access type.  I'll check this out, thanks.

Comment: The placement of annotations determines the type only if they are all of same type: all on fields or all on getters. If you want to mix both, you must use the trick above.